# different properties under one node

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have an object I am using an xml-serializer to serialize. Is it possible to essentially insert an arbitrary Child Root node, and assign certain properties to belong to this root node?

A few properties
        public int ID { get; set; }

```
    public object ActivityType { get; set; }

    public int ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string RelatedObjects { get; set; }

    public string Parameters { get; set; }

    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public List<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }

    public bool OnlySaveIfValid { get; set; }
```

Now, when I serialize this with xml serialize I get:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FNActivity>
  <ID>0</ID>
  <ObjectId>0</ObjectId>
  <Conditions>
   <Condition>
    <Critical>false</Critical>
    <ValidIf>false</ValidIf>
    <IsValid>false</IsValid>
  </Condition>
  <Condition>
    <Critical>false</Critical>
    <ValidIf>false</ValidIf>
    <IsValid>false</IsValid>
    </Condition>
  </Conditions>
 <OnlySaveIfValid>false</OnlySaveIfValid>
</FNActivity>
```

The Xml I want to get is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FNActivity>
  <ID>0</ID>
  <ObjectId>0</ObjectId>
       **<VALIDATION>
         <Conditions>
           <Condition>
           <Critical>false</Critical>
           <ValidIf>false</ValidIf>
           <IsValid>false</IsValid>
         </Condition>
         <Condition>
          <Critical>false</Critical>
          <ValidIf>false</ValidIf>
          <IsValid>false</IsValid>
         </Condition>
        </Conditions>
        <OnlySaveIfValid>false</OnlySaveIfValid>
      **</VALIDATION>
  </FNActivity>
```

Comment: I think the easiest would be to simply create a `VALIDATION` class/object to store your conditions in. You could implement `IXmlSerializable` to manually do it, but it seems overkill. The best is to create an object model that closely matches your XML model, then separate your serialization concerns from your application concerns.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I somewhat agree if this is the only instance, however there are multiple areas where we are converting from using XML scehmas that are human written and XML schemas that are written programatically, so readability is still somewhat desired. Also, restructuring code have it serialize the way I want doesn't seem like the correct solution.

Comment: Well, what is the "correct solution" is relative. You're using the `XmlSerializer` class so, generally speaking, you can only use it the way it is intended; in that sense, the "correct solution" is to separate your concerns and build your data models as the XmlSerializer deems is correct. If you are working with two different schemas to connect to the same underlying data model, then this is even more important to separate your serialization concerns from your application logic concerns. And as I suggested, you can still leverage `IXmlSerializable` and insert the node manually.

Comment: IXmlSerializable ...I will research this. thanks